# What is the maximum size that maxReceivedMessageSize can be set to for a NetNamedPipeBinding?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, netnamedpipebinding

I noticed that 2147483647 seems to be a popular choice for maxReceivedMessageSize but is this the limit?

Comment: On the other hand, you might want to consider that setting it to 2 GB of message size means your WCF server will potentially have to deal with several messages of up to 2 GB in size simultaneously - can it do that?? Marc

Comment: It is if you have a 32bit server...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Nope, the limit is [Int64.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.maxvalue.aspx)<sup>[1](http://blogs.msdn.com/yassers/archive/2006/01/21/515887.aspx)</sup> which is: 9223372036854775807

Comment: In the web.config-File, only the Int32-limit seems to work. Maybe it's a parsing issue.

Comment: When setting this value through code I get `ArgumentOutOfRange` exception for this parameter.

Answer (score 9):

MaxMessageReceivedSize in basicHttpBinding appears to be an int32 - setting it over the max value of an int32 results in:

This factory buffers messages, so the message sizes must be in the range of an integer value.
Parameter name: bindingElement.MaxReceivedMessageSize

Comment: Nope, it's Int64 (long): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.maxreceivedmessagesize%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX

Answer (score 3):

`MaxReceivedMessageSize` and `MaxBufferSize` must  same value and `MaxBufferSize` is `Int32`.

Comment: Not true - MaxBufferSize is only used if you are using Buffering. If you are using Streaming, then it is ignored. This is why MaxReceivedMessageSize is Int64 and can be different to MaxBufferSize.

Comment: Do you mean maxBufferPoolSize and maxReceivedMessageSize?

Comment: BasicHttpBinding MaxBufferSize is Int32, but MaxReceivedMessageSize is Int64. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.maxbuffersize%28v=vs.100%29.aspx