# WCF Error because The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded

Tags: asp.net, wcf-data-services

i make WCF service on server side to return binary (bytes) of file..
i just can return binary of txt file,otherwise it's say "The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element."

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          transferMode="Buffered"
          messageEncoding="Text"
          textEncoding="utf-8"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
               useDefaultWebProxy="true" >
        <security mode="None" />
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
                 maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                 maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

can you give me solution?

i need your help..thanks before :)

here is client code side (app.config)

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:3724/Service.svc" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
              contract="ServiceReference1.IService"
              name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
  </client>
```

this client is desktop application not website

Comment: refer to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004717/what-is-the-maximum-size-that-maxreceivedmessagesize-can-be-set-to-for-a-netname

Comment: See if this helps: [Error: the maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24897891/745969)

Comment: @Tim where i put tag endpoint? :)

Comment: @PeterYohanes It should be another section in your config file. That's where you specify the service ABC - Address, Binding, Contract - for your service.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy i make endpoint tag after bindings tag..but it error..i'm sorry,i never use it before.so i'm confused to apply that..
<services>
   
      <service>
         <endpoint address="/Service.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
          bindingCongifuration="wsBinding" contract="service.IService"/>
      </service>
   </services>

Comment: @PeterYohanes - See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the binding you defined to an endpoint you create.  Here's an example:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
             maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
             transferMode="Buffered"
             messageEncoding="Text"
             textEncoding="utf-8"
             bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
             useDefaultWebProxy="true" >
      <security mode="None" />
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services> 
  <service> 
    <endpoint address="/Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              bindingCongifuration="basicHttp" 
              contract="service.IService"/> 
  </service> 
</services>
```

A couple of things to note - in your comment, your service endpoint was using wsHttpBinding, but you defined `basicHttpBinding` in your `<bindings>` section.  Also, the `bindingConfiguration` attribute must be the name assigned to the binding defined.  My example above is based on the original posted config file.

Alternatively, if you are using .NET 4.0 or later, you can define a binding in the `<bindings>` setting and set it as the default definition for that binding by omitting the `name` attribute on the `<binding>` element.

By default, .NET 4.0+ uses `basicHttpBinding` for `http`.  You can change this in the config file in the `<protocolMapping>` section (which is contained in the `<system.serviceModel>` section).  For example, if you wanted to use `wsHttpBinding` for all `http` requests, you would do this:

```
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
</protocolMapping>
```

**Added Client Example**

The client side would look very similar, except you'd have a `<clients>` section instead of a `<services>` section.  Note that some of the settings on the binding apply to the machine (client or server) the application is on, and setting them on one side of the client-server relationship will have no effect on the other side (like `maxReceivedMessageSize`, for example).  Generally the binding type and security have to agree, and in practice it's usually easier to just use the same bindings on both ends, but it is possible to have a scenario where one side would have different buffers or other items.

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" allowCookies="true"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
             maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
             transferMode="Buffered"
             messageEncoding="Text"
             textEncoding="utf-8"
             bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
             useDefaultWebProxy="true" >
      <security mode="None" />
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="localhost:3724/Service.svc" 
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService" 
            contract="ServiceReference1.IService" 
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" /> 
</client>
```

Comment: i use .NET 4.0+ and i write my code as your example..
i don't know why,but it not working..
thanks and sorry troubling you Tim :)

Comment: @PeterYohanes - I just reread your question.  Is the error appearing on the client (i.e., when you get the data from the server)?  If so, you need to make the changes in the client's config, not the server.  If this is the case, please post the `<system.serviceModel>` section of your client config in your original question?  I'll take a look.

Comment: sorry to late reply
not only error on client,but if d invoke that WCF on server it's error too..can you give me any idea?

Comment: @PeterYohanes - The binding you define in the client doesn't have any values set, so you're getting the default values.  You need to have the binding values match what's on your server, and then use that binding configuration in your client as well.  Very similar to my example above, but the endpoint would be in the `<client>` section.

Comment: in my client side,i have set 

<client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:3724/Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService" contract="ServiceReference1.IService"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
        </client>

and then i copy paste all of binding on server to client side?

Comment: yes,thanks Tim..
but it arise new error,it's say "The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large."
why it can show that? :)