# WCF file transfer service that is throwing QuotaExceededException

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF file transfer service that is throwing `QuotaExceededException` when my file is bigger than 1.5 GB. I've reviewed similar posts but I'm not understanding why I'm getting the exception or how to resolve it.

> System.ServiceModel.QuotaExceededException: The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (2147483647) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

Here's a snip of my client `app.config`:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransfer" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
             transferMode="Streamed" 
             receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="01:30:00" 
             openTimeout="00:30:00" closeTimeout="00:30:00">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                      maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                      maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Here's a snip of my `web.config`:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="FileTransfer" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
             maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" 
             receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="01:30:00" 
             openTimeout="00:30:00" closeTimeout="00:30:00">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                      maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                      maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Here's a snip of the service code that's throwing the exception:

```
var sum = 0;  

try  
{  
    FileStream targetStream;  
    var sourceStream = request.FileByteStream;  

    using (targetStream = new FileStream(tfile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))  
    {  
        const int bufferLen = 1024 * 64;  
        var buffer = new byte[bufferLen];  
        int count;  

        while ((count = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen)) > 0)  
        {  
            targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);  
            sum += count;  
        }  

        targetStream.Close();  
        sourceStream.Close();  
    }  
}  
catch (Exception ex)  
{  
    Logger.Debug("sum = " + sum);  // sum = 1610609664 bytes (this is 1.499997 GB)  
    Logger.LogException(ex);  
}
```

I can't get anything larger that 1.5 GB

Comment: The `maxReceivedMessageSize` is the total data transferred, including all headers and the size of the data as it is actually transferred. If transferring as a soap message and the data is being Base64 encoded for example, the actual data transferred is going to have a lot of overhead, so you probably are hitting that 2GB limit with a 1.5GB file. You need to increase the limit (it will take Int64.MaxValue, but possibly only in code for the binding, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004717/what-is-the-maximum-size-that-maxreceivedmessagesize-can-be-set-to-for-a-netname)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks steve16351, I didn't realize that maxReceivedMessageSize was a long. I updated my config files with Int64.MaxValue (9223372036854775807) and was able to upload a 6.8 GB file.

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="FileTransfer" maxReceivedMessageSize="9223372036854775807" maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="01:30:00" openTimeout="00:30:00" closeTimeout="00:30:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

And I changed my sum to a long, works great now.

```
var sum = 0L;  
try  
{  
    FileStream targetStream;  
    var sourceStream = request.FileByteStream;  
    using (targetStream = new FileStream(tfile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))  
    {  
        const int bufferLen = 1024 * 64;  
        var buffer = new byte[bufferLen];  
        int count;  
        while ((count = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen)) > 0)  
        {  
            targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);  
            sum += count;  
        }  
        targetStream.Close();  
        sourceStream.Close();  
    }  
}  
catch (Exception ex)  
{  
    Logger.Debug("sum = " + sum);  // no more exception  
    Logger.LogException(ex);  
}
```